# Is spacetime supersymmetry realized at TeV scale? and more questions on supersymmetry

Tags: supersymmetry, dark-matter, symmetry-breaking, beyond-the-standard-model

1. Is spacetime supersymmetry realized at TeV scale?
2. If so, what is the mechanism of supersymmetry breaking?
3. Does supersymmetry stabilize the electroweak scale, preventing high quantum corrections?
4. Does the lightest supersymmetric particle (LSP or Lightest Supersymmetric Particle) comprise dark matter?

Comment: We do not know if supersymmetry is realized in nature. We do not see supersymmetric particles around so the supersymmetry (if it exists at all) must be broken at low energies. For same reason, specially the hierarchy problem, it is believed that supersymmetry is realized above some scale around $1000\, GeV$.

Comment: Basically there are two ways SUSY can be broken: either spontaneously or explicitly. Spontaneous supersymmetry breaking is based on a (super) Higgs mechanism whereas in explicit supersymmetry breaking the Lagrangian itself has suitable chosen terms that breaks SUSY.

Comment: This question asks too many individual questions (e.g. "At what scale is SUSY realized?" and "Is the lightest superpartner dark matter?" are sufficiently unrelated questions that you should ask them separately) and doesn't give enough information about the framework you want it answered in - there is a large class of supersymmetric theories and none of them is currently favoured by experiment, so it's not clear from which viewpoint one should attempt to answer it.